# Finding the gradient vector of 3D function

Tags: python, 3d, gradient, point, contour

I have the following function

```
def f(x,y):
    return -(x**2+y**2-2)
```

The function is hemishpere,at the surface of this function there is a point (x0,y0,z0),I need to find the gradient vector that shows the maximum direction.

I have this code

```
Ex,Ey= np.gradient(f(X,Y))
EX, EY = np.meshgrid(Ex,Ey)
Ex_2=max(list(map(max, Ex)))
Ey_2=max(list(map(max, Ey)))
```

I would like to know if there is another way to find the vector toward the maximum of the function(gradient vector) with its initial point in (x0,y0)?

*The function f(x,y) is given by the user which means I can not define df because I do not know the function that will be given

Comment: I'm probably missing something but what do you mean any other way? Isnt' `f` trivial do differentiate? You could just define a function `df(x,y)` that returns `-2*x-2*y` and pass it numpy arrays.

Comment: the function f(x,y) is given by the user which means I can not define df because I do not know the function that will be given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you have presented, I can only see two reasons to look for alternatives to `np.gradient`:

1. You don't want to use numerical differentiation (which is what `np.gradient` does) because of precision issues.
2. You can't afford to use numpy (This seems unlikely, but maybe you have a very constrained embedded platform?).

In the first case, I think that you can either look into symbolic or automatic differentiation. The former is usually much slower and also is a bit less straight-forward to work with. Automatic differentiation is usually much more precise than numerical differentiation and is readily available in a number of libraries, that you can chose depending on how much constraints you want to impose on the code that the user provides, *e.g.*

```
#Autograd (pseudocode)
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def f(x,y):
    #do something with x,y
    #...
    return some_value

df=grad(f)
u=df(1,1) #gradient of f at point (1,1)
```

or

```
#pytorch, might be overkill in your case
import torch
def f(x,y):
    """
    x,y should be torch.Tensor
    """ 
    #do stuff
u=f(x,y)
u.backward()
x.grad #this is the gradient w.r.t x
```

If the main concern is the second case and you don't want to use extra libraries, one possibility is for you to compute derivatives with finite differences yourself, which will not add any constraints on your user but might hurt precision depending on what their function is. The other option is to enforce constraints on the function that the user provides: either make it mandatory for it to also return its own Jacobian so that you can use it in the chain rule on your side, or define your own types such as [Dual Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) that will let you compute derivatives but will force the user to derive from that type when defining function/variables.